# Convert Railway oriented failure track to Rx friendly errors

Tags: f#, functional-programming, system.reactive, monads, monad-transformers

I'm using a library that takes the results as two-track values (success and failure).In the `Observable.map` function bodies I often get an observable from success track of a function, and I don't know how to handle them (at `Observable.map` body).

In the other words I often get stuck in situations that the result looks something like the following (of course it's the simplest one):

```
Rop.Result<IObservable<Rop.Result<IObservable,Messages>,Messages>
```

On one hand, translating messages back to exceptions and raising them seems wired to me, and on the other hand, the error handlers are impure functions and I'd rather not pass them around.

I wonder what is the standard and clean solution to handle the failures from two-track results at the `Observable.map` body.

**Update: Example**

This is the simplest ever sample of the problem :

```
module problem
open FSharp.Control.Reactive

type Person = {FirstName:string;LastName:string}

let getPersonByLastName lastName =

    let persons =   Observable.toObservable<|seq{
            yield {FirstName="Jhone";LastName="Smith"}
            yield {FirstName="Joe";LastName="Smith"}
            yield {FirstName="Jack";LastName="Smith"}
            }

    Rop.succeed persons

let main =
  let final =
    Observable.single("Smith")
    |>Observable.map(fun lastName -> 
                    let personResults = getPersonByLastName lastName
                    personResults
                    )

  0
```

In this example the `final` result of the expression is of type `IObservable<Result<IObservable<Person>,ErrorMessage list>>` but I want it to be `IObservable<Person>`, because further `Observable` transformations will end up pretty dirty and complicated expressions.

Comment: I can't get your code to compile. A [mcve] can only be complete when it compiles or presents no other problem except yours.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Thank you @Enigmativity. The problem I'm asking about is pretty theoretical, and I provided the example in order to make the question more understandable. Anyway, I added `module` and `main ` function. I can't add `Rop` module here. It works on my machine now.

Comment: I still can't compile your code. Theoretical or not you're looking for answers and you're not getting any. An [mcve] is the quickest way yo get answers.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use ``map`` instead of ``bind``. But I can't say for sure. If you add a code or a link to gist for the 'rop' stuff it would be easier.

Comment: Sure @Gustavo . https://github.com/swlaschin/Railway-Oriented-Programming-Example/blob/master/src/FsRopExample/Rop.fs `mapR` means `map` in that library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the simplest level, what you need here is a way to extract and then surface an `IObservable` that is wrapped in a `RopResult`. One part of the solution was already mentioned in the comments (`Observable.bind`), the other is a function `RopResult<IObservable<'a>, 'b> -> IObservable<RopResult<'a,'b>>`.

To get that, you need to deconstruct the `RopResult` and handle both the cases. So to put that in context of your stated problem:

```
Observable.single("Smith")
|>Observable.bind(fun lastName -> 
    match getPersonByLastName lastName with
    | Rop.RopResult.Success (next, msgs) -> 
        next |> Observable.map (fun x -> Rop.RopResult.Success (x, msgs))
    | Rop.RopResult.Failure msgs ->
        Observable.result <| Rop.RopResult.Failure msgs)
```

Is this good code though? I don't think so. You could make it slightly better perhaps by using other ROP api functions, or by using a computation expression for the body of the bind here, but that's not the point.

Both reactive programming using Observables, and "railway-oriented programming" are useful tools as long as they can capture and abstract away some element of complexity involved in whatever computation you're modelling. This works because they're build on primitives that compose well together. When you try to "interleave" the two like this, you forfeit some of that as you have to manage that composition yourself.

I would say [you're better off using exceptions](https://eiriktsarpalis.wordpress.com/2017/02/19/youre-better-off-using-exceptions) here - especially since Observables have a built-in support for them.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use *success with message* it seems pretty natural to combine `Observable` and `RopResult`.

```
exception ROPExn of string list
let combine = function
                         | Success (x, _) -> x
                         | Failure errors -> Observable.Throw(ROPExn(errors))                  
let main =
  let final =  Observable.single("Smith")  |> Observable.bind(getPersonByLastName >> combine)
  let handleError = function
      |ROPExn(list) -> printfn "ROP fail"
      | _ -> printfn "error"
  let subscription = final |> Observable.subscribeWithCallbacks (fun p -> printfn "%s" p.FirstName) handleError ignore
```