# How to declare a generic exception types in F#

Tags: generics, exception, f#

How can I define an exception like the following?

```
exception CustomExn<'TMessage> of 'TMessage list
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do that according to [F# Spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf) (page 164, 8.11)
Probably good candidate for proposal

Comment: I was half-expecting to find a guideline somewhere saying that exceptions with generic type arguments are ill-advised, but I failed to find one. I would still say they're best avoided - you probably don't really need that level of detail on an exception and if you do, you're probably looking at normal control flow rather than an exception path.

Comment: @scrwtp: I use it for converting monadic outputs of third-party libraries to exceptions. This is a use case sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956854/convert-railway-oriented-failure-track-to-rx-friendly-errors/49966795#49966795

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you can just inherit from System.Exception?

```
type CustomExn<'TMessage> (message:'TMessage list) =
    inherit System.Exception ()  

let test =
    try
        raise (CustomExn["string"] )
    with 
    | :? CustomExn<string> -> "CustomExn of string"
    | :? CustomExn<int> -> "CustomExn of int"
    | _ ->  "Everything else"
```

Comment: Won't work cause in `try with` `with` clause won't be generic

Comment: Well, in your answer you done quite the same. And it's caught with try/with when you specify closed exception type.

Comment: This is not better than just [make non-generic exn definitions](https://gist.github.com/Szer/e2530de5a55a4176a26707af0212505c)

Comment: Yes it is, because you need to define non-generic exn definition for each closed type. The whole point of generic is lost then.

Comment: In your case you MUST know what exact kind of closed generic type your method could throw (and this is not in function signature) or you will lose your message list. The best way, as I said is using `Result<'a, 'b list>`

Answer (score 5):

Not sure it is possible with F# `Exception Definitions` according to [specs](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf) (page 164-165)

This one also **NOT A GOOD SOLUTION** because `try with` will only catch `ExceptionList<string>` in this case so there is no good way to make it generic

```
type ExceptionList<'a>(msgList: 'a list) =
    inherit Exception()
    member __.MessageList = msgList

let mock() = 
    raise <| ExceptionList(["failed"])

try
    mock() //raises ExceptionList<string>
with
    //this catch block won't fire, because it is not generic, it is ExceptionList<obj>
    | :? ExceptionList<_> as exnList -> 
        exnList.MessageList 
        |> List.iter (printfn "%A")
```

The better way though: `Result<'a,'b list>`:

```
let mock'() = 
    if DateTime.Now.Ticks % 2L = 0L 
    then Ok()
    else Error(["failed"])

let result = mock'()
match result with
| Ok _ -> printfn "Ok!"
| Error (msgList) -> 
      msgList
      |> List.iter (printfn "%A")
```

**Added** There is a workaround with type loss:

```
type ExceptionList(msgList: obj list) =
    inherit Exception()
    member __.MessageList = msgList

// Here is F# exception definition
exception CustomException of ExceptionList

let failwithMany msgs = 
    raise <| CustomException (ExceptionList(msgs))

let mock() =
    //zero type checking here
    failwithMany[1;2;"a";[];"failed"]

try
    mock()
with
    // exnList is list of objects
    | CustomException exnList ->
        exnList.MessageList 
        |> List.iter (printfn "%A")
```